# JSTL JSP Two databases

Tags: database, jsp, jstl

I got webaplication (JSP JSTL MYSQL Database) It like rental (you can add things, show catalog) It's work on mysql but now i have do add second database (i choose postresql) When adding item to database it have to go to both Is it possible with jstl? At the momen i'm using single database with something like that:

```
<sql:setDataSource var="dbsource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/wypozyczalnia?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8" user="klimcur"  password="123"/>
<sql:update dataSource="${dbsource}" var="result">
    INSERT INTO Aparaty(Producent, Model, Rozdzielczosc, Koszt, Link, imei) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);
    <sql:param value="${param.Producent}" />
    <sql:param value="${param.Model}" />
    <sql:param value="${param.Rozdzielczosc}" />
    <sql:param value="${param.Koszt}" />
    <sql:param value="${param.Link}" />
    <sql:param value="${param.imei}" />
</sql:update>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible in **JSTL** you can have multiple database connection

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>

<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot1" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://ip/db" user=""  password=""/>
<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot1}" sql="select * from employees" var="result1" />

<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
       <th>Emp ID</th>
       <th>First Name</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${result1.rows}">
        <tr>
           <td><c:out value="${row.empid}"/></td>
           <td><c:out value="${row.ename}"/></td>         
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>

<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot2" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://ip/db" user=""  password=""/>
<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot2}" sql="select * from employees" var="result2" />

<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
       <th>Emp ID</th>
       <th>First Name</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${result2.rows}">
        <tr>
           <td><c:out value="${row.empid}"/></td>
           <td><c:out value="${row.ename}"/></td>         
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```